# An error occurred when verifying security for the message when client try to consume WCF

Tags: wcf

I am trying to use wcf service authentication without SSL by using this link :
http://webservices20.blogspot.in/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html

Every thing goes fine till i publish the service.but when i try to consume service with asp.net webClient then it throw

An error occurred when verifying security for the message exception

Server stack trace:

```
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

my web config file is :

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<extensions>
<bindingExtensions>
<add name="clearUsernameBinding"   type="WebServices20.BindingExtenions.ClearUsernameCollectionElement, ClearUsernameBinding" />
  </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>
<bindings>
  <clearUsernameBinding>
    <binding name="myClearUsernameBinding" messageVersion="Soap12">
    </binding>
  </clearUsernameBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SampleServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="QService.MyUserNameValidator,QService" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="QService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="SampleServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint binding="clearUsernameBinding" bindingConfiguration="myClearUsernameBinding" contract="QService.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

and my client code is :

```
  ServiceReference1.ServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        obj.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
        obj.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
        Response.Write(obj.GetData(45));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is the above config your server or client config

Comment: Is you service and client both in the same project. If no then why does your server config have a client endpoint section? Apart from that your service element is not proper. The name attribute value should be namespace.servicename and the same for Contract attribute in endpoint elemnent, they need to be fully qualified names

Comment: thanks rajesh for this info now check config.Is it right now ?If yes then i still getting same error

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using clearUserName binding? Also seems like your stack trace doesnt give enough information. Is it possible for your to upload a sample for us to take a look?

Comment: Rajesh i am using clearUserName because i want to authenticate wcf service without using certificates.In fact you can say that i want to authenticate only by username and password